# Print via bluetooth printer from my ios application?

Tags: ios, xcode, printing, bluetooth

Print photo via bluetooth printer from my application.

Printer already connected via bluetooth.

when i click on UIButton and printer print the photo that connected to the phone.

How can i do that ?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/index.html

Comment: Give me some example link to learn from that directly

Comment: And the reason why you did not do it yourself is ....?

Answer (score -2):

iOS does not support printing via bluetooth.It supports printing using WiFi via AirPrint.

List of supported AirPrinters.
http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4356

Here is an example to print PDF using AirPrint.

```
- (void)callPrintPDF {
UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
UIPrintInteractionController *pic = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
pic.delegate = self;
pic.printInfo = printInfo;
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:self.strPDFUrl];
pic.printingItem = url;

void (^completionHandler)(UIPrintInteractionController *, BOOL, NSError *) =
    ^(UIPrintInteractionController *printController, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {
    if (!completed && error) {
        NSLog(@"Printing could not complete because of error: %@", error);
    }
};
[pic presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];
}
```